# How can I access the previous/next element in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I iterate through an ArrayList this way:

```
for (T t : list){
  ...
}
```

When I did this, I never thought I had to access the previous and next elements of this element. Now my code is huge. It costs a lot if I rewrite it with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Look into code cleanup tools which can translate these two methods.

Comment: 1)  Don't delete the post, that's not how things work at Stack Overflow.  2)  Add your answer to the existing list of answers, and accept it - that way, we know it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution it is simple in fact, but I cannot delete this post already because it has answers..

I just added `T t = list.get(i);` in the second for-loop, all other code remains unchanged.

Comment: It makes your algorithm much more complex. Using iterator, accessing previous/next element is O(1) and using get() is O(n).

Answer (score 25):

No, the for-each loop is meant to abstract the `Iterator<E>` which is under the hood. Accessing it would allow you to retrieve the previous element:

```
ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
  T t = it.next();
  T prev = it.previous();
}
```

but you can't do it directly with the for-each.

Comment: Wouldn't this skip the last item?

Comment: What happens when you call previous() method at first index?

Comment: from documentation - (Note that alternating calls
     * to {next} and {previous} will return the same
     * element repeatedly.)

Answer (score 5):

As an answer to the title, rather than the question(with considerations to concurrent operations)...

```
T current;
T previous;
{
    ListIterator<T> lit = list.listIterator(index);
    current = lit.hasNext()?lit.next():null;
    previous = lit.hasPrevious()?lit.previous():null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access any element in ArrayList by using the method get(index).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        array.add(1);
        array.add(2);
        array.add(3);

        for(int i=1; i<array.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(array.get(i-1));
            System.out.println(array.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @xenteros Where did O(n^2) come from?  `ArrayList.get(int)` is O(1)

Comment: @antak There were times when I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution too. It was next.

For next: `letters.get(letters.indexOf(')')+1)`

For previous: `letters.get(letters.indexOf(')')-1)`

Comment: Hi Kenzo1, you should have a look at Markdown syntax to nicely format your answers.