# How to get current and Next arraylist index in for loop using java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a Java application and I am having one `int ArrayList`.

I am getting current `ArrayList` index but please guide me on how to get the next `ArrayList` index by using a `for` loop.

I'm trying to do this using the code below but I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfbound` exception:

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

suppose arraylist is having below elements.

```
temp1={10,20,30}
```

How can we use for loop to achieve this:

```
for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size;i++)<--size is 3
{
    int t1=temp1.get(i);
    int t2=temp1.get(i+1); // <---here i want next index
}
```

I want to do addition of 1st-10 and 20
                                                2nd-20 and 30
                                                3rd-30 and 10

Is it possible to achieve this? It should work for any size of `ArrayList`. I am open to different approaches to achieve this.

Comment: Change `t2=temp1.get(i+1)` to `t2=temp1.get((i+1) % arrayList.size())`.

Comment: Most simple questions already have answers in StackOverflow. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850468/how-can-i-access-the-previous-next-element-in-an-arraylist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If for the last index you want to add it with the first index value, you should use the `next position` index as - `(i+1)%arraylist.size()` . Also, for an `ArrayList` size is a function, not a variable.

So the loop would be -

```
for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++)<--size is 3
{
    int t1=temp1.get(i);
    int t2=temp1.get((i+1)%arraylist.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modified your code snippet.Check the following

```
            import java.util.ArrayList;

            public class Main {


                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    temp1.add(10);
                    temp1.add(20);
                    temp1.add(30);
                           for(int i=0;i<temp1.size()-1;i++)
                           {
                               int t1=temp1.get(i);
                               int t2=temp1.get(i+1); 
                               System.out.println(t1+t2);
                               if(i==temp1.size()-2){
                                   System.out.println(temp1.get(0)+temp1.get(temp1.size()-1));
                               }
                           }
                }
            }
```

Output :

30

50

40